# Import cookies to Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, import, cookies

I have exported some cookies from Firefox (using the Cookies Manager+ add-on). How can import them into Internet Explorer 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import/Export is found on the FILE menu.

Here is a walkthru to [import cookies](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/86785-internet-explorer-import-export-cookies.html) into Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It works fine but is there any faster resolution cause the IE wizard really slows me down?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Are you doing this more than once?